# RS485: is "Y" multidrop allowed?

Tags: rs485

I imagine that the proper way to implement an RS485 multidrop bus is the following:

[image]

What happens if, in order to save cables, I connect the same 5 nodes above using this other topology?

[image]

- Will it works?
- If no, why?
- If "maybe", under which circumstances will it work?

---

*P.S.: yes! I know that MEGA has three Serials and, as such, I could implement two different BUSses (1: Mega<->Mega<->Mega; 2: Mega<->Nano<->Nano), but this will increase the complexity of the software I'm running, as it needs some hacking in order to play nicely with two distinct RS-485 busses;*

*P.P.S.: This is the bus discussed in [this other question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/hardware-network-infrastructure-for-a-fully-arduino-based-home-automation-projec)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At low speeds and short distances that won't be a problem.

At high speeds (megabits per second) and long distances (hundreds of meters) you may get reflections unless you get the termination just right.

Comment: Can you please tell values you think is reasonable to call "short distance" and "low speed" in this context?

Comment: @Bacco tens of meters and 115200 baud, I'd call short distance and low speed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!